# Gstreamer x264enc + tee + mp4mux

Tags: gstreamer, tee

Okey I have a problem Iam wrote this pipeline :

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -e location=rtsp://ip/url ! decodebin ! tee name=split split. ! queue ! autovideosink  split. ! queue ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mp4mux ! filesink location = test.mp4
```

But what bothers me is filesink.After I stop pipeline I get corrupted file I know  problem is that mp4mux doesn't recive on eos message and he can't finalize file but I don't know how can I solve that problem .Could somebody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Okey I found a solution I added sync = false after every sink element and everything is ok now